# Splitting around an outer character in Perl. Minimal assumptions within group

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a hard time adapting the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936468/splitting-a-string-around-outer-delimiters-respecting-character-groups) to the following problem:

I would like to split the following string:

```
my $string = "foo{age}, bar{height}. something_else. baz{weight,so='yes',brothers=john.smith}.test{some}"
```

around the **outer dots**. The result should be an array holding

```
("foo{age}, bar{height}", 
 "foo{weight,parents='yes',brothers=john.smith}", 
 "test{some}")
```

I would like to **avoid making assumptions** about what's inside the groups inside `{}`.

How can I do this in Perl?

I tried adapting the following:

```
print join(",",split(/,\s*(?=\w+{[a-z,]+})/g, $string));
```

by replacing what's inside the character class `[]` without success.

### Update:

The only characters **not** allowed within a `{}` group are `{` or `}`

Comment: Can you have nested `{...}` inside the outer `{...}`?

Comment: @m.buettner I just clarified that. Thanks

Comment: The [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17936618/1521179) for your other question still works here, you just have to change the separator: `/\G ($regex) [.] \s*/xg`.

Comment: @amon. GOT IT. Sorry I didn't quite understand the last part of your answer. I think I do now. Sorry for the potential duplicate. I will make that clear in the OP.

Comment: Are your outside dots always exactly next to a closing `}` symbol? This would make it very easy, but I am assuming that it is just a coincidence of your example to look like that.

Comment: @amon, actually just changing `[,;]` to  `[.]` does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @JosephMyers. I clarified that. The dots don't need to be next to a closing `}`.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have an empty field, i.e., two consecutive dots with nothing between them? This also affects how simple the solution can be.

Comment: @JosephMyers - Yes that's definitely possible.

Comment: Never mind, I see that you have a working solution already. I had one running in a perl test file based on the same idea as my sentence suggested and in m.buettner's solution, but I wanted to know whether I could optimize it.

Comment: @user815423426 Ah yes, I'm sorry. I wrote an answer that extends my previous approach to this problem, and I find it rather readable. However, m.buettner’s solution is quite nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are not dealing with nested braces, the periods you want are those which are not "immediately" followed by a closing `}`. Where "immediately" means, without an opening `{` in between:

```
split(/[.]\s*(?![^{]*[}])/g, $string)
```

Alternatively, to *match* the parts you're interested in:

```
(?:[^.{}]|[{][^{}]*[}])+
```

Which can be ["unrolled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043454/using-regexes-how-to-efficiently-match-strings-between-double-quotes-with-embed) to:

```
[^.{}]*(?:[{][^{}]*[}][^.{}]*)*
```

Comment: +1. Thanks. This is a good solution, but I updated the OP, since the dots dot not necessarily have to be next to a closing `}`

Comment: @user815423426 my solution does not assume that (in neither of the two approaches)

Comment: Got it. I guess that you are right, since it's a weak assumption. I can probably work with this assumption, although the spirit of the post is to make *minimal assumptions* (effectly no assumptions) about what's inside `{}`

Comment: @m.buettner: forget my precedent comment, because I saw the pattern like this: `[^\s.{](?:[^{.]*{[^}]*})+`

Comment: Nice solution! Your split is great, although your other two are incorrect. E.g., "foo{age}, bar{height}. baz{weight,so='yes',brothers=john.smith}.test{some}" -> "foo", "", "age", "", ", bar", "", "height", "", "", " baz", "", "weight,so='yes',brothers=john", "", "smith", "", "", "test", "", "some", "", ""

Comment: @JosephMyers oh right, they were both missing a quantifier. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would have solved the problem:

1. We define an item:

   ```
   my $item = qr/ \w+ (?: [{] [^{}]* [}] )? /x;
   ```

   That is, some word characters and optionally a section inside braces.
2. We define item groups, separated by comma:

   ```
   my $item_group = qr/$item \s* (?: , \s* $item \s* )*/x;
   ```

   That is, an `$item` followed by zero or more comma-item sequences.
3. We extract the results by matching for an item group that is followed by a period or the end of string:

   ```
   my @result = $string =~ /\G ($item_group) \s* (?: [.] \s* | \z)/xg;
   ```

Output:

```
(
  "foo{age}, bar{height}",
  "something_else",
  "baz{weight,so='yes',brothers=john.smith}",
  "test{some}",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a match instead of a split, matching the alternatives of braces with anything between them (except braces) or non-braces with anything except for a dot.